# Default argument for STL container in templated function

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a templated function of the form

```
template <typename T>
void my_fct( vector<T> ){...}
```

and would like to provide a default argument, such that the my_fct() can also be called. Clearly, the compiler does not know what type "T" is in that case, but is there some way to give it  a default type in that case?

I tried to pass an empty vector of type double

```
template <typename T>
void my_fct( vector<T> = vector<double> ){...}
```

but this does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: `void my_fct(const vector<T>& = vector<T>())` will also work, to avoid copying the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `T` a default argument:

```
template <typename T = double>
void my_fct( vector<T> = vector<T>() ) {...}
```

So when the user calls the function with zero arguments, the type of the vector will be `std::vector<double>` initialized as a default argument.